Laravel reverb not working when an event is triggered
Problem Description
I'm experiencing an issue where Laravel Reverb is not triggering events when called. The event appears to be processed by the queue worker but doesn't show up in the Reverb terminal.
Environment

Laravel (11.0)
Laravel Reverb
Local development environment

Configuration
.env Configuration
BROADCAST_DRIVER=reverb
BROADCAST_CONNECTION=reverb
REVERB_APP_ID=237641
REVERB_APP_KEY=28gciw5trm4wbncyiyoe
REVERB_APP_SECRET=z8ufizq2lwwyk9yhqmhm
REVERB_HOST="localhost"
REVERB_PORT=8080
REVERB_SCHEME=http

BroadcastServiceProvider
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Broadcast::routes();
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}

broadcasting.php Configuration
'connections' => [
    'reverb' => [
        'driver' => 'reverb',
        'app_id' => env('REVERB_APP_ID'),
        'key' => env('REVERB_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('REVERB_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_host' => env('REVERB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'app_port' => env('REVERB_PORT', 8080),
        'client_host' => env('REVERB_CLIENT_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'client_port' => env('REVERB_CLIENT_PORT', 8080),
        'scheme' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'http'),
        'path' => env('REVERB_PATH', '/reverb'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REVERB_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1'),
            'useTLS' => env('REVERB_USE_TLS', false),
            'host' => env('REVERB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('REVERB_PORT', 8080),
            'scheme' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'http'),
        ],
    ],
]

Route Definition
Route::get('/broadcast', function () {
    broadcast(new Example());
    return response()->json(['status' => 'Event broadcasted']);
});

Event Class (Example.php)
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class Example implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        \Log::info('Broadcasting on chat channel');
        return [
            new Channel('chat')
        ];
    }

    public function broadcastWith(): array
    {
        return [
            'message' => 'Test message',
            'time' => now()->toDateTimeString()
        ];
    }
}

Current Behavior
When hitting the /broadcast endpoint, the queue worker processes the job:
php artisan queue:work
INFO Processing jobs from the [default] queue.  
2024-12-20 06:10:01 App\Events\Example ................................................. RUNNING
[2024-12-20 06:10:01] local.INFO: Broadcasting on chat channel  
2024-12-20 06:10:01 App\Events\Example ............................................ 37.51ms DONE

However, the Reverb terminal shows no events being broadcasted.
What I've Tried

Reinstalling the library
Verifying all configuration settings
Ensuring the queue worker is running

I hope that when an event is triggered it will be visible in the terminal where the reverb is running
